How to display the final line number
Emacs doesn't show the line number if it is the last line and the line is empty. Apparently, this is by design, but in the mode line, it shows the line number.

My line number configuration is like this:
(setq display-line-numbers-type 'visual)
(global-display-line-numbers-mode -1)
(require 'conf-mode)
(dolist (mode '(org-mode-hook       ; All the modes to have line numbers
         prog-mode-hook
         conf-mode-hook
         text-mode-hook
         dired-mode-hook
         Man-mode-hook))
  (add-hook mode '(lambda () (display-line-numbers-mode 1))))

How can I get Emacs to display the line number (on the left-hand side with all the other line numbers) when I'm on the last, empty line?

It's by design because there is no "last empty line" -- I can't think of any software which would read a file with a final newline and treat it as an additional line. (Something might do it, but it would be weird.) If you have a file with three lines and each line ends with a newline character, pretty much everything is going to call that "three lines" rather than "four lines".

The mode line is forced to show the next number because it only shows one value, and so it needs a way to differentiate between the last line of the buffer and where the cursor is now -- it would be confusing, otherwise. You can think of the mode line as showing the potential line number, and the left edge as the actual number of lines in the buffer.

(Not that I know for sure that both features were implemented with the same interpretation -- display-line-numbers-mode came along decades after line-number-mode -- but I believe the above is very much the reasoning for how display-line-numbers-mode behaves.)

If I remember correctly, there is either a bug report or a discussion on the Emacs Devel mailing list between Eli Z. and myself from several years ago where he stated that the end of the buffer on a line all by itself (without a line number) is "a feature".  In my tinkering with the C source code back then, I created a test for no man's land and use a custom indicator at that location -- however, that is not a part of the standard Emacs and was never incorporated.  Maybe someday I will pick-up that project again ...

This is one of the weirder edge cases in computing. Nobody can really agree on it, but POSIX did weigh in on the matter. The POSIX definition of a line is a sequence of characters followed by a newline character. Thus the newline character does not separate lines of text, it terminates lines of text. If you add some characters after the final newline, many programs won’t count it as a line. Try running printf "foo\nbar" | wc -l, for example.

Yeah, I guess it's just what it is. But it's weird because Vim shows the number of an empty line

I previously submitted a bug report on this particular issue, and the author of the native line numbers (Eli Zaretskii) responded by stating that this behavior is "a feature".
https://lists.gnu.org/r/bug-gnu-emacs/2017-08/msg01039.html
From:   Eli Z.
Subject:    bug#28247: Display native line number on last line of buffer (when empty line).
Date:   Sun, 27 Aug 2017 05:40:20 +0300

> Date: Sat, 26 Aug 2017 15:29:36 -0700
> From: Keith David B. <esq@...>
> 
> Emacs does not display a native line number on the last line of the buffer 
> unless there is something there in addition to the cursor.

This is a feature: "the last line" is not actually a line, there's no
character there.


